# IIS WCF Service Division/Separation

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis

I'm currently in the middle of a large ASP.NET application with many WCF services. Currently in IIS, all these services are listed under one application called Services.

I'm concerned that with more being added to our servers all the time and the uptake of our application increases, this is probably not the best way to manage things. Currently the VS project has a "web service host web application", which contains all the .svc files to be hosted. The advantage of having it all in one is the obvious use of the web.config for all services. The disadvantage is that if we need to do an update or deal with a critical issue, all our services are brought down at once, rather than those few that we know the problem is located.

I'm wondering if it is possible to keep this "host web application", but split the application into different "sub-applications" using separate Application Pools and allow VS to publish to individual services. I don't know if splitting it into folders under the "host web application" and hosting these as individual applications will work.

Or is the only way to have lots of host applications to run in separate application pools?

TL;DR; Should I split our application with all services into 5-6 applications with a few services?

Comment: You certainly can deploy the same code base multiple times and disable some services by configuration. Can you detail what "critical issues" you have in mind? It is rare that one service having a problem (a bug?!) would affect another.

Comment: By critical issues I mean events where we encounter an issue with one of our services which requires us to quickly patch it or update it. To my knowledge, the only way to do this would be to bring all of the services down if they are all on one application/app pool. I'm just experimenting with sub folders/nesting services now :)

Comment: So you can't have 30s downtime for deployments? How do you do regular deployments, then? Maybe you should fix *that*. Put a (software) load-balancer before IIS. When you want to deploy, deploy to a standby IIS site and warm it up. Then, switch the LB routing over. Zero downtime.

Comment: I wish deployments took 30s on our connection... That makes perfect sense to do, but I'm not sure how I would go about that (or even if I can get approval). Is it a case of just creating a second site in IIS that is identical (apart from the update), and switching it with a load balancer? Would there not be conflicts with sharing host names, IP's, ports etc.?

Comment: The LB is the public endpoint. It gets the externally visible IP and potentially HTTPS. The internal sites run on different internal IPs or internal host names. Maybe you should ask a new question on hot to perform pauseless deployments. This comment thread just derails the question.

Comment: Actually there are such questions. If I don't find a suitable one I'll ask myself.

Comment: Good point, I think I'll look into LB and the associated wizardry. I'll try and get this closed for now to avoid more confusion.